# windows - plain shared memory between 2 processes (no file mapping, no pipe, no other extra)

Tags: c, windows, shared-memory

How to have an isolated part of memory, that is NOT at all backed to any file or extra management layers such as piping and that can be shared between two dedicated processes on the same Windows machine?

Majority of articles point me into the direction of CreateFileMapping. Let's start from there:

How does CreateFileMapping with hFile=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE actually work?
According to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

it
"...creates a file mapping object of a specified size that is backed by the system paging file instead of by a file in the file system..."

Assume I write something into the memory which is mapped by CreateFileMapping with hFile=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Under which conditions will this content be written to the page file on disk?

Also my understanding of what motivates the use of shared memory is to keep performance up and optimized. Why is the article "Creating Named Shared Memory"
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) refering to 
CreateFileMapping, if there is not a single attribute combination, that would prevent writing to files, e.g. the page file?

Going back to the original question: I am afraid, that CreateFileMapping is not good enough... So what would work?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that *all* the memory that your process uses either is a straight file mapping, or is is backed by the paging file? What you get with `malloc`, or even the stack itself falls in this second category.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130301-00/?p=5093

Comment: Just trust the OS that it will only swap the data out to disk if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstand what it means for memory to be "backed" by the system paging file.  (Don't feel bad; Raymond Chen has described the text you quoted from MSDN as "[one of the most misunderstood sentences in the Win32 documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130301-00/?p=5093).") Almost all of the computer's memory is "backed" by *something* on disk; only the "non-paged pool", used exclusively by the kernel and as little as possible, isn't.  If a page isn't backed by an ordinary named file, then it's backed by the system paging file.  The operating system won't write pages out to the system paging file unless it needs to, but it can if it does need to.

This architecture is intended to ensure that processes can be *completely* "paged out" of RAM when they have nothing to do.  This used to be much more important than it is nowadays, but it's still valuable; a typical Windows desktop will have dozens of processes "idle" waiting for events (e.g. needing to spool a print job) that may *never happen*.  Those processes can get paged out and the memory can be put to more constructive use.

`CreateFileMapping` with `hfile=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is, in fact, what you want.  As long as the processes sharing the memory are actively doing stuff with it, it will remain resident in RAM and there will be no performance problem.  If they go idle, yeah, it may get paged out, but that's fine because they're not doing anything with it.

You *can* direct the system not to page out a chunk of memory; that's what [VirtualLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx) is for.  But it's meant to be used for small chunks of memory containing *secret* information, where writing it to the page file could conceivably leak the secret.  The MSDN page warns you that "Each version of Windows has a limit on the maximum number of pages a process can lock. This limit is intentionally small to avoid severe performance degradation."

Comment: Using the system page file like that (specifying INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) you aren't going to be able to share between multiple processes. You could create a shared section in a .DLL and load that library into multiple processes but only objects of static size can be shared that way (you could have a char * in the shared section and the pointer itself would be shared between processes but but where that pointer references is going to be different unless it is deliberately pointed at memory that has been loaded at the same base address).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: "Using the system page file like that (specifying INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) you aren't going to be able to share between multiple processes" false, you just need to pass a name as the last parameter.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, a file mapping is really a Section object, which can be named (global or session-local) and secured, so any process with access can open it.  Among other things, a Section describes a block of prototype page table entries that act as a layer of indirection between process PTEs and the page frame database. When a page is invalid in a process, the memory manager can use the page frame number from the prototype PTE to make the process PTE valid. If the prototype is invalid, then, in this case, it's going to reference the page offset in the pagefile on disk.

Comment: @zwol, thank you for clarification. I was desparately looking for any information about if at the moment I do CreateFileMapping with hfile=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE windows holds itself by writing any kind of at least management information to the page file (e.g. maintaining an page file internal directory in a synchronous way). After your answer I assume not.

Comment: @Quicker, memory is accessed in pages (e.g. 4 KiB per page in x64), and every process has a page table with an entry per page. If a PTE is valid, the hardware memory management unit (MMU) uses it to translate a virtual address in a page to its corresponding physical memory page frame number. If it's not valid, the fault gets handled in software by the OS memory manager. For shared memory, an invalid PTE will point at a common prototype PTE, which in turn may be valid and point at the physical memory page, or it may be invalid (swapped out) and point at an offset in the paging file on disk.